# Can not load a file that uses standard libraries in haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

Hi I use GHCI and can normally load my files. Now I need to load a file that uses random. I get this error.

```
Chatterbot.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘System.Random’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import System.Random
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is very weird since it works for my friend who also have just installed GHCI and did nothing other than me. The main difference is that I am on windows. I really don t understand this and have tried googling a bit and many people speak about stack but it seems annoying and It obviously works for my friend without it.

Thanks in advance

EDIT problem solved. I needed to update cabal then I ran cabal install random and it worked well. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: You need to install the `random` package, for example with `cabal install random`, or add it as a dependency to your `.cabal` file.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a version of [cabal-install](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html) >= 3.0 (check with `cabal --version`), then, instead of creating a cabal package, you can move to an empty folder and [type](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build.html#cabal-v2-install):

```
cabal install --lib --package-env . random
```

This creates a [*.ghc.environment* file](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-environments) in the folder. `ghci` sessions started inside that folder will pick it up, and they will be able to `import System.Random`.

If that works correctly, you might want to install "random" globally so that any invocation of ghci can use it:

```
cabal install --lib random
```

This creates/modifies the [global environment file](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build.html#cabal-v2-install) located at `~/.ghc/$ARCH-$OS-$GHCVER/environments/default`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650929/cabal-cannot-find-locally-sourced-yet-correctly-installed-packages/60659835#60659835

Answer (score 1):

The [**`System.Random`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random/docs/System-Random.html) is part of the [**`random`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random), not of the `base` package. You thus should install it. If you for example use `cabal`, you can install it with `cabal install random`.

If you use Haskell stack for example, you can add it to your `package-name.cabal` file:

```
  -- …
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , random >=1.0 && <2
```