# Hiding versions of random from GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am working with the `newsynth` package and am running into a bug that I am starting to suspect has to do with the update `random-1.2.0` over the summer (`newsynth` was last updated in late 2019, and `random-1.2.0` came out in June. I have run `cabal update` since then, which is why both seem to be installed.) Here is the code that I ran in GHCi:

```
 λ> import System.Random
 λ> import Quantum.Synthesis.Ring
 λ> import Quantum.Synthesis.Diophantine
 λ> g <- getStdGen
 λ> diophantine g (RootTwo 5 0)

<interactive>:5:1: error:
    • No instance for (random-1.1:System.Random.RandomGen StdGen)
        arising from a use of ‘diophantine’
      There are instances for similar types:
        instance random-1.1:System.Random.RandomGen
                   random-1.1:System.Random.StdGen
          -- Defined in ‘random-1.1:System.Random’
    • In the expression: diophantine g (RootTwo 5 0)
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = diophantine g (RootTwo 5 0)
```

As was suggested to me in another SO post, I tried hiding the other copy of `random` from GHCi. I ran

```
$ ghc-pkg --global --package-db ~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db list random
~/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/package.conf.d
    (no packages)
~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db
    random-1.1
    random-1.2.0
```

so I tried `$ ghc-pkg --global --package-db ~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db hide random-1.2.0`.
However, when the bug persisted, I also tried `$ ghc-pkg --global --package-db ~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db hide random-1.1` (just to make sure `hide` did what I thought it would), yet inexplicably found that in GHCi (even after restarting Terminal) I was able to run  `λ> import System.Random` despite all known instances of `random` being hidden. Am I hiding packages in the wrong way?

Thank you in advance.

---

(I asked a somewhat related question the other day but since I think this issue is kinda different I thought it made sense be separate. If this is not the case I can update the other post.)

Comment: `ghc-pkg` is a very low-level instrument and most times is not the right tool for the task. How do you run GHCi? You should be using `cabal` or `stack` to avoid version conflicts. E.g. for `cabal`, you should be able to get a consistent environment with that package available with `cabal v2-repl -b newsynth`.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn I just enter GHCi thru the command line -- I'm currently just trying to get the hang of a few functions from `newsynth`. However, I also don't currently use Cabal or Stack for anything. Is that what I should transition to? I don't know anything about how to actually use Cabal -- what will `cabal v2-repl -b newsynth` do?

Comment: As I said: you should use `cabal` or `stack` for getting to any packages except `base`, as `ghc-pkg` is not supposed for “normal users”. As to your question: `cabal v2-repl` opens a GHCi session configured by `cabal`. The `-b <list-of-pacakges>` brings the packages into that GHCi session.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn Ok thank you, I will use Cabal going forward. When I ran `import System.Random` it returned `Ambiguous module name ‘System.Random’:
      it was found in multiple packages: random-1.1 random-1.2.0`. I googled for ways to disambiguate, but didn't find anything that seemed to match this. Is there a simple way to do it that I'm overlooking?

Comment: When you say "When I ran" how do you run it? You need to provide more details about what you're doing if you hope to get useful advice.

Comment: If you did install cabal, you may need to start with (assuming you're on a Unix) `rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal`. This would clean whatever inconsistent state you got to previously. Also, make sure you have a recent Cabal (3.0 is good, but 3.2 is better).

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn Sorry, I'll be more precise. In Terminal I entered `cabal v2-repl -b newsynth` and then when the GHCi command line came up I entered `import System.Random`, which returned `<no location info>: error: Ambuguous module name...`. I next ran `rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal`, as you suggested, then `cabal update`, then after `cabal v2-repl -b newsynth` I think `import System.Random` and the `newsynth` calls are working. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good to know! Please, consider endorsing my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cabal or stack when you want to manage packages. But first, reset to clean state:

```
rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal
cabal update
cabal v2-repl -b newsynth
```

This will get you into a GHCi session with the desired package available.

Answer (score 2):

I you want to work directly in ghci without going through `cabal repl` or `stack ghci`, one way is to create a *local* [GHC package environment](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html?highlight=package%20environment#package-environments) in a folder, using [cabal-install](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-install):

```
cabal install --lib --constraint="random == 1.1" --package-env .  random
```

Besides "random" itself, you'll need to explicitly list other packages that you want to be present in the environment. Likewise, you might add multiple `--constraint` arguments.

This will create a file named ".ghc.environment.xxx" in the folder, which should be picked up by standalone ghci or ghc invocations made there.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61067274/1364288

Comment: So if I need `random`, `newsynth`, and `linear`, say, I'd do `cabal install --lib --constraint="random == 1.1" --package-env .  random newsynth linear`?

Comment: @zjs Yes, it should work. Also, those .ghc.environment files are just text files and they can be deleted without ill effects (the compiled binaries are stored elsewhere and can be reused by Cabal).

Comment: If your purpose is to get to newsynth, you shouldn’t be specifying constraints on random: this doesn’t make any sense from the package manger point of view. Your package manager (either cabal or stack) will be able to figure it out. Ask only for what you really need.